# How to import a class of project2 in project1?

Tags: python-3.x

I have project1 and project2 and their structures as:

project1:

```
F:\sampleproj1
   com
     sampleproj1
       main.py
```

project2:

```
E:\sampleproj2
    com
      sampleproj2
         xyz.py
```

How can I import a class for `eg:mainclass`(user defined) from `project2` in `project1`?

I tried my luck as:

### In main.py (sampleproj1):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('E:/sampleproj2/com/sampleproj2')
```

then

```
from sampleproj2.com.sampleproj2.xyz import mainclass
```

This doesn't work, and I guess I am wrong with the path appending....Any help is appreciated

Comment: and that may be empty too?

Comment: what matters too is where are you executing the code ? what does this mean mate?

Comment: Maybe try answers from this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: When I try to import the class with '__init__.py' included , (Pycharm)IDE throwing error even while importing!

Comment: where do you launch the program ? from Pycharm or with a command line from the shell?

Comment: Pycharm itself, should i have to from command line?

Comment: `sys.path.append('E:/sampleproj2/com/sampleproj2')` allows you to import any .py file of this folder, even if `__init__.py` is not here. Could you share the exact error you are facing ?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sampleproj2'

Comment: try with `from xyz import mainclass`

Comment: This worked mate, even it is showing IDE import error, why i don't know exactly

Comment: maybe pycharm cannot detect the `sys.path.append()` to adjust the warnings.

Comment: try with this, tested in linux not sure about windows.

`import sys`
`sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")`

Answer (score 0):

I found answer from @PRMoureu as

```
import sys
sys.path.append('E:/sampleproj2/com/sampleproj2')
```

Then simply,

```
from xyz import mainclass
```

Note: If you are using Pycharm as IDE then you might observe warnings while importing,just ignore it